# How do I use session variable as a default value for form field in python django?

Tags: python, django

In forms.py,

```
class UpdateForm(forms.Form):
   n1 = request.session['name']
   name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
           'style':'margin-bottom:10px; width:600px; height:50px ;align:right',
           'required':'',
           'value':n1,
           'placeholder':'Name of Institute',
           'class':'form-control'}), label=(""))
```

It shows an error that returns 'request' is not defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the initial kwarg on the form. Here are the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values).
Your view:

```
def view(request):
    initial_name = request.session['name']
    form = UpdateForm(initial={'name': initial_name})
```

Your form:

```
class UpdateForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'style':'margin-bottom:10px; width:600px; height:50px ;align:right',
                   'required':'',
                   'placeholder':'Name of Institute',
                   'class':'form-control'}),
            label=(""))
```